# T-SQL Query - How to not include some results from different row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data something like below.

```
ID | Value 
------------    
 1 | A 
 1 | B 
 1 | C 
 2 | A 
 2 | C
 3 | C
```

I'm trying to get ID which has A but not including B.

In this case, I should only get ID 2 as a result.

If I query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (VALUE = 'A' AND VALUE <> 'B')
```

I get 1 and 2 as a result.

Is this even possible from this database structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude any ID's that contain the value 'B'. you can do this with a left join and a check for null... i.e. no match.

```
select d.*
from data d
    left join (select id from data where value = 'B') x --exclude these
        on d.id = x.id
where x.id is null
    and d.value = 'A'
```

Comment: @shinya If there is more than one row with the same `ID` and `Value=A` this solution would return several rows with the same `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you accepted an answer, I'll write another variant. I think it is easier to write and understand. In terms of performance you have to check how different variants work on your system with your real data.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Value char(1));

INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (1, 'C');
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (2, 'A');
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (2, 'C');
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES (3, 'C');

SELECT ID FROM @T WHERE Value = 'A'

EXCEPT

SELECT ID FROM @T WHERE Value = 'B'
```

Result set:

```
ID
2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you include `Value` in the result set, this approach returns incorrect results.

Comment: @GB, of course it will return incorrect result. This solution is for getting `IDs` only, as requested in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

here is another query for it:

```
select distinct tb.ID from tbl_name tb
where tb.Value='A' and tb.ID not in(select distinct tbl.ID from tbl_name tbl
where tbl.Value='B')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM table t1
 WHERE t1.value = 'A'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table t2
                     WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                       AND t2.value = 'B' );
```